# How to save cookies with pickle using webbrowser

Tags: python

I use the script below to save cookies with webbdriver! But for convenience, I want to save cookies with webbrowser, is there any way to save cookies with webbrowser? I didn't find much documentation about it. Thank you .

```
import pickle
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
pickle.dump( driver.get_cookies() , open("cookies.pkl","wb"))
```

Comment: I save cookies using this method as well. I think this is the most common way to do it.

Comment: @Mykola Zotko  , When using the webdriver, we must log in with the webdriver, which is a bit time consuming .  I think using webbrowser will be more convenient

Comment: You can start the webdriver, log in manually and then save your cookies.

Comment: @Mykola Zotko  I  save many cookies so I want to save with  browser to save time